# Preloading with the Deezer Android SDK

Tags: android, deezer

In the JavaScript SDK there's `dz.player.preloadTrack` which works great to smoothen track transitions. An analogous API does not appear to be available in the Deezer Android SDK — is this planned or is the app expected to create two Player instances where the next track is on "stand-by" in the other instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed for now there is no preloading feature in the Android SDK, but we will look into this for a next version of the SDK. 
For now indeed you might want to create a second player to get a smooth transition between two tracks. Please note that you can have up to 5 Players simultaneously in Deezer's SDK.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds great!  I have now implemented preloading using two Deezer players. However, it seems like the second player starts filling audio data into the buffer used by the first player, because even though the second player only goes to READY state I can hear its audio interleaved with the output of the first player. Is this a bug or can you confirm that this scenario works and I must be doing something silly somewhere?

Comment: I've not tried this scenario to be honest, but this should work as long as you call the play method only when you wan't to play the track.

Comment: Ok. I start preloading 10 seconds before, and the audio glitches are audible just after preloading starts (well before .play() is called).

Comment: I'll try this and see what it gives (do you test this in an emulator or a real device ? )

Comment: Same behavior both in emulator and on a real device (tested on HTC One).